# How to get current user infomation/context within adaptive cards spfx?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, modern-experience, adaptive-cards, spfx-aces

[Build your first SharePoint Adaptive Card Extension](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/viva/get-started/build-first-sharepoint-adaptive-card-extension)

I am following the tutorials/docs in above link and I have created my first ACE. However, I can't see in the docs or by googling, how to get the current user context.

Can anybody point me in the right direction, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the current user details from `this.context` in `HelloWorldAdaptiveCardExtension.ts`.

For example:

I have this code in `onInit()` method:

```
let userEmail: string = this.context.pageContext.user.email;
```

You can also check this sample which uses current user details in ACE (line no. 48): [Hybrid Work Employee Check-in from Adaptive Card Extension](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-aces/blob/65f7b5dce9ad3e040384d5af5ef4356e98eb4485/samples/ImageCard-HybridWork-Checkin/src/adaptiveCardExtensions/hybridWorkCheckin/HybridWorkCheckinAdaptiveCardExtension.ts)

Comment: Ganesh you are the man <3